# It is possible to install qt 5.10 with qt creator 7+?

Tags: qt-creator, windows-11, qt5.10

I've to recreate a work environment in a new pc and I would like to use the newest Qt Creator to work on a project that was developed in 5.10 but the maintenace tool does not allow to select that version:

[image: Maintenance tool: component selection]

I'm currently using windows 11, should I install Qt Creator 4.x that was shipped with 5.10 and then install the new Qt Creator over it?

it is actually possible to have what I would like to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you are not seeing Qt 5.10 there, I do.

Anyhow, you can always install Qt Creator from an offline installer (https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qtcreator/ or from https://account.qt.io) and use the "Link with Qt" banner that is shown when you start that (if the banner doesn't show up, the same functionality is accessible via Tools > Options > Kits > Qt Versions > Link with Qt). Point that to the base directory of a Qt offline or online installer to make everything known to that Qt Creator installation automatically.

Comment: I was just about to write the solution with Link with Qt! Thanks a lot